# How do I read the bundle in context from within a JSP custom tag?

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, tags, resourcebundle

I have a JSP 2.0 file containing calls to a custom tag that needs to know what bundle is currently in use on the page, so it can look up some resources. The custom tag is written in Java. The bundle can change depending what page the custom tag is used on, but the resource key will always be the same, so I wanted to use the existing `fmt:bundle` tag to specify this, e.g.:

```
<fmt:bundle basename="myBundle">
    <custom:tag title="text.title"/>
</fmt:bundle>
```

I've been assuming that the `fmt:bundle` tag can be read from (or otherwise provides its environment to) the inner tags, where the custom tag is in the above example (in the same way that it interacts with the `fmt:message` tag), but I haven't been able to figure out how to access the `LocalizationContext` that `fmt:bundle` supposedly defines from within the Java that defines the custom tag.

I've tried

```
LocalizationContext lc = (LocalizationContext)Config.get(
        pageContext.getRequest(),Config.FMT_LOCALIZATION_CONTEXT);
ResourceBundle rb = lc.getResourceBundle();
String s =rb.getKey(title);
```

but I just get

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle
    java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key text.title
```

which seems to indicate that is not the right place to look (I guess that has fallen through to the default bundle?).

One workaround might be to pass the bundle name into the custom tag, but I'm sure what I want to achieve should be possible, if only my poor JSP know-how didn't let me down, so I hope someone can help me get a better understanding!

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2):

According to the JSTL specification there is a class named [LocaleSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/fmt/LocaleSupport.html) that implements the bundle lookup and may be used by any tag handler implementation that needs to produce localized messages.

Comment: Thanks. `LocaleSupport` looks very useful and I'll give that a try. In the mean time I have looked at the source for the `MessageSupport` tag  and done what is done there when no bundle tag is specified (looks for a `BundleSupport` classed ancestor and gets the `LocalizationContext` from it). Although to make this work, I also needed to ensure the LocalizationContext was in the page scope rather than the request scope (which seems reasonable in my application.)